# Gibt es eine beispielhafte Beschreibung der im Bayrischen gebräuchlichen internationalen Lautschrift?

Tags: expression, dialect, bavarian, phonetics

Im Bayrischen gibt es einige gebräuchliche Laute, die in der Verschriftlichung nur schwer abbildbar sind.
So zum Beispiel den schon fast klischeehaften *Oachkatzlschwoaf*, zu dem de.wictionary,org schreibt:

[image: Screenshot of article linked above]

Wie man sieht, ist die Abbildung in IPA (internationales Lautschrift Alphabet) Alles andere als trivial: *[ˈoa̯xkat͡sl̩ˌʃwoa̯f]*

Gibt es eine Hilfstabelle mit Beispielen, die man zur Übersetzung nach IPA verwenden kann?

Comment: Die Frage hat eigentlich nichts mit Bayrisch zu tun, oder? Du suchst nur eine Tabelle für Aussprachebeispiele des IPA, oder?

Comment: @jonathan Ich meinte schon mit spezifisch Bayrischen Wortbeispielen. _Weanerisch_ ist da z.B. zwar vesrändlich, aber subtil doch viel zu verschieden.

Comment: For me, the easiest way to deal with IPA is to find an IPA to speech converter on the internet (such as http://ipa-reader.xyz/), paste the offending material into it and let the computer sound it out for you. You'll probably need to select the correct language since, despite the I part of IPA, it does make a difference.

Comment: PS Wikitionary has an actual human saying too: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Datei:De-Oachkatzlschowaf.ogg

Answer (score 1):

Mir ist leider keine beispielhafte Beschreibung des im Bayrischen gebräuchlichen internationalen phonetischen Alphabets bekannt.

Das Problem liegt insbesondere darin, dass die bairische Dialektologie traditionell gar nicht das internationale phonetische Alphabet verwendet, sondern andere Lautschriften, die oft als Teuthonista-Lautschrift bezeichnet werden. Im Gegensatz zum internationalen phonetischen Alphabet sind diese Lautschriften jedoch nicht allgemein definiert. Vielmehr handelt es sich um eine variierende Liste von Zeichen, die je nach Bedarf definiert werden. Also ist eine allgemeine Definition oder beispielhafte Beschreibung dieser Zeichen nicht möglich. Typisch für Teuthonista-Lautschriften sind Zeichen wie *ä* für Laute wie [ɛ, æ, a] oder *å* für Laute wie [ɒ, ɑ].

Selbstverständlich wird gelegentlich auch das internationale phonetische Alphabet für bairische Dialekte verwendet. Ein Beispiel dafür ist der englische Wikipedia-Artikel [Northern Bavarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Bavarian). Die dort angeführten Beispiele gelten allerdings nur für das Nordbairische.

Answer (score 0):

> Gibt es eine Hilfstabelle mit Beispielen, die man zur Übersetzung nach IPA verwenden kann?

Ja, ich habe [diese](https://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/bairisch-lernen/aussprache-bayrisch/) hier auf [Bayrisches Wörterbuch](https://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/) gefunden<sup>1</sup>:

```
Einfache Laute zur Veranschaulichung der Aussprache


    IPA à   sehr helles à, wie in Para:de, Karat, Spagat; engl. butler, dust.

    Beispiele:   Radi [rà:de] = Rettich; Madl [mà:dl] = Mädchen

    IPA ådumpfes a, zum offenen o klingend, wie in Wort, Post, Moll, toll.

    Beispiele:   i hab [håb]= ich habe, i mag [må:g]= ich mag


    IPA a    Normales a, wie in Fahrkarte, Straßenbelag, Lager.

    Beispiele:   Walli [walle] = Walburga, Abrui [abrui] = April, Datzn [dazzn] = Tatze


    IPA   e    geschlossenes e wie in Rebe, Leben, Fee.

    Beispiele:   Bredl [bre:dl] = Brett, des [de:s] = das, Schlegel [schle:gl] = schwerer Hammer


    IPA   ä    das offene e wie schriftdeutsch nett, fett wird bairisch als ä gesprochen.

    Beispiele:   sehgn [säng] = sehen, Besn [bä:sn] = Besen

    IPA   o    geschlossenes o wie schriftdeutsch Lob, Soße

    Beispiele:   Topferl [dobbfàl] = Töpfchen, Kopferl [kobbfàl] = Köpfchen


Diphtonge – Doppellaute


    IPA   äi   Geld [gäid], Feld [fäid], beinand [bäinand],
(vergleichbar mit dem „a“ in englischen Wörtern wie base, case)


    IPA   au   haun [haun] = hauen, schaugn [schaung] = schauen, Daum [daum] = Taube

    IPA   ai (ei)   um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden, verwende ich in der Lautschrift ausschließlich ai.

Leut [laid] = Leute, Beidl [baidl] = Beutel, Sack

    IPA   ià   miad [miàd] = müde, Fiass [Fiàss] = Füße

    IPA   oà   alloa [àlloà] = allein, oans [oàns]

    IPA   oi   Hoiz [hoiz], Stoiz [schdoizz]

    IPA   ou   Koud [koud] = Erde, Erdreich, Broud [broud] = Brot

    IPA   uà   Kuah [kuà] = Kuh, Ruah [ruà] = Ruhe

    IPA   ui   Bruin [bruin] = Brille, Fuim [fuim] = Film

[:] Doppelpunkt hinter einem Vokal: der Selbstlaut wird lang gedehnt z.B. gehen = geh = [ge:], Käse = Kas = [kà:s], nein = naa = [nà:]

Unterstrichene Vokale bzw. Silben werden betont. Konsequenterweise habe ich auch Vokale in Wörtern mit nur einer Silbe unterstrichen.
```

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Ich bitte den vorformatierten Text zu entschuldigen, aber solange Stack Exchange common mark Tabellen noch nicht offiziell unterstützt ...</sub>

Comment: Es handelt sich _nicht_ um IPA (und die Quelle behauptet das auch nicht), sondern um eine [Teuthonista](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teuthonista_(Lautschrift))-Variante. Teuthonista ist aber im Unterschied zum IPA keine vordefinierte Lautschrift, sondern eher ein Satz von Zeichen, der in jedem Werk definiert wird, wo man ihn verwendet. Deshalb ist dazu auch keine umfassende Übersicht zu finden.

Answer (score -1):

Du schreibst, die Wiedergabe der Laute in IPA sei alles andere als trivial, aber wirklich schwer ist IPA auch nicht zu lesen. Die [Liste der IPA-Zeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen) finde ich da sehr hilfreich.

Wounst as owa auf boarisch hom mechst, doun schaugst hoid in da boarisch Wikipedia noch, do homs a a [Listn vo de IPA-Zaichn](https://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listn_vo_de_IPA-Zaichn), ober hoit mit boarische Beispü. Owa natiali a nua ba de Zeichn, de im Boarischen fuakumman. Iwaroi sist san di Beispü hoit vo de Sprochn, wo ma suiche Laute vawendt.

Ich schreibe jetzt lieber wieder auf Standarddeutsch weiter, weil das für die Meisten Leser ja doch verständlicher ist.

Die Buchstaben, mit denen wir heute deutsche Texte schreiben, wurden ja weder für die deutsche Sprache noch für Bairisch entwickelt. Diese Buchstaben wurden vor ungefähr 3500 bis 3800 Jahren in Ägypten für eine semitische Sprache verwendet und sind in ihrer Urform von ägyptischen Hieroglyphen inspiriert. Diese Buchstabenschrift wurde dann im Lauf der Jahrtausende kreuz und quer über den Erdball getragen und hunderte Male verändert. Aus dieser gemeinsamen Wurzel entwickelten sich alle Alphabetschriften auf diesem Planeten (lateinisch, griechisch, kyrillisch, alle indischen Schriftsysteme, armenisch, georgisch, koptisch, glagolitisch, usw.)<sup>1</sup>

Daher ist es kein Wunder, dass die Zeichen, die wir zum Schrieben verwenden, nicht exakt mit dem Lauten übereinstimmen, die wir zum Sprechen verwenden. Da gibt es Buchstaben, die für unterschiedliche Laute stehen, wie z.B. das C (*»Circus«*) und das V (*»Vater - Vase«*), und es gibt Laute, die durch mehrere Buchstaben wiedergegeben werden (*»Schach«* hat 6 Buchstaben, aber nur 3 Laute), und Buchstaben, die für mehrere Laute stehen (*»zu«* hat 2 Buchstaben, aber 3 Laute: *tsu*). Die Wörter »Phi« und »Vieh« werden gleich ausgesprochen, aber für *»modern«* gibt es zwei unterschiedliche Aussprachen (*»Das nasse Holz wird bald modern.« »Dieser Schnitt ist wieder modern.«*) - Kurz: Schriftzeichen und Sprachlaute lassen sich nur sehr ungenau aufeinander abbilden.

Im Standarddeutsch, das wir alle als Kinder in der Schule gelernt haben, und das wir jeden Tag lesen und die meisten von uns auch schrieben, haben wir uns längst an diese seltsamen Regelungen gewöhnt, und nehmen sie als normal war. Aber Bairisch hat keine genormte Rechtschreibung. Das kann jeder schreiben wie man will. Es kommt eigentlich nur darauf an, dass der Leser das versteht, was der Schreiben ausdrücken wollte.

Das viel größere Problem besteht aber darin, dass Bairisch einige Laute verwendet, die im Standarddeutsch nicht vorkommen (siehe [Bairische Phonologie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairisch#Phonologie)). Während man sich bei den "normalen" Lauten ja noch ohne weiteres an der Schreibweise des Standarddeutschen orientieren kann, ist das bei den rein bairischen Lauten deutlich schwieriger.

Wenn man das mit lateinischen Buchstaben schreiben will, ohne auf die IPA-Lautschrift zurückzugreifen (die man übrigens leicht an einem einzigen verregneten Nachmittag lernen kann), dann muss man improvisieren. Trotzdem hat sich auch in der schriftlichen Wiedergabe der bairischen Sprache ein gewisser Quasi-Standard entwickelt.

Beispielsweise schreibt man das dunkle A, das in der Mitte zwischen Hochdeutschen *»a«* und *»o«* liegt, die beide auch im Bairischen vorkommen, mit einem Ring: *»å«*

> Da J**a**ga j**å**gt Hiaschn und haßt J**o**hann. = Der Jäger jagt Hirsche und heißt Johann.

Im Bairischen gibt es auch das stumme L, das oft geschrieben wird, obwohl es nicht ausgesprochen wird. So ist z.B. das L in meinem Namen *Schölnast*<sup>2</sup> eigentlich ein stummes L. Dort, wo mein Name herkommt (Oststeiermark) spricht man ihn ohne L aus: »Schönast«, und auch ich selbst melde mich so am Telefon. Aber auch das Wort *»Öl«* wird im Bairischen ohne L ausgesprochen und trotzdem mit L geschrieben. Und die Ortsnamen *Wels* und *Melk* verlieren in der bairischen Aussprache ihr L (*»Wös«, »Mök«*). Dieses L wird beim Sprechen aber trotzdem mitgedacht, daher findet man es auch häufig in der schriftlichen Wiedergabe (*»Wöls«, »Mölk«*).

Auch in der bairischen Wikipedia wird das stumme L geschrieben, z.B. im Wort *»Beispiel«*, das als *»Beispü«* ausgesprochen wird, in Wikipedia aber konsequent mit L (also *»Beispül«*) geschrieben wird.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Für alle, die mehr über die Entwicklung der Alphabetschriften erfahren wollen, habe ich einen Buchtipp: »Das ABC der Menschheit - Eine Weltgeschichte des Alphabets« von Matthias Heine. Verlag Hoffmann und Campe, 2020, 250 Seiten. [ISBN 978-3-455-00852-4](https://www.hoffmann-und-campe.de/buch-info/das-abc-der-menschheit-buch-12243/)</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>»Schölnast« ist der Name eines Musikinstruments: Ein *Schöln-Ast*, Hochdeutsch *Schellen-Ast*</sub>

Comment: Diese Antwort geht überhaupt nicht auf die im Bairischen gebräuchliche internationale Lautschrift ein.